# How to generate a signed APK in intelliJ

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, keytool

I wonder how to get a certificate and sign the apk in `intelliJ 13` (`Win 7 x64`). I followed a tutorial about Generating a new release key at:

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/generating-a-signed-apk-using-a-wizard.html

I tried to create a new keystore and fill in required info, but encounter the following error:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file exists, but is empty: 'path name'
```

Path name is the location that I store my keys, but is empty, as I expect intelliJ to generate a new key and store that key in the location. I wonder is there a streamline method to generate a key and sign the app automatically provided required information.

The workaround is simply adding a file name (`*.jks`) after the path name selected from the folder tree.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking this is what's happening:

> If Keytool is already in your PATH, it might be pointing to a symlink
>   at /usr/bin/keytool. In this case, check the symlink target to be sure
>   it points to the Keytool in the JDK.
>   [[source]](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#setup)

If the symlink does point to the right location of your keytool, then the next thing I would attempt is to try signing the application [manually](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode) through the command line. This is to eliminate IntelliJ as a possible cause of your problem. Once you're able to sign your key with the command line, then you can delete the key and try again with intelliJ.

Comment: Hi, I am new to android development, so I only know keytool can generate me a key that can be used to sign apk. So in order to use keytool, I need to add the path of keytool in system variable `Path`?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using `Win 7 x64`.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not on Windows. I can't give you detailed instructions for that OS. Please try signing your apk manually through the DOS command line. The keytool should be located in the bin folder of your Java JDK (not your Java JRE, but your Java JDK). Also, while you're doing that, double-check your environment variables, the right path may already be in there. If it isn't, add it in there. If it is, don't touch it. Also, if it still doesn't work, it wouldn't hurt to read what's in your C:\Users\<user>\.android\ folder. Again, I'm sorry I can't be more specific since I'm only a Linux user.